# My mac address changes but internet not working?

Tags: mac

When I change my mac addreess i cannot connect to the internet. I am running Ubuntu 16.10 with a computer that i made my adapter says wlp40. I can use a software on Windows to change my mac but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/886392/edit) your question and give us more information about what OS you are running, what type of computer.  Any more detail you can think of would really help us help you.

Comment: Maybe your router has a MAC filter to only allow certain devices to connect to the internet?

Comment: I added more info to my pc

Comment: How did you change your MAC ?

Comment: I installed macchanger and macchanger GUI both ways didn't work